# C++ error: passing ‘const umap_int {aka const std::unordered_map<int, int>}’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, reference, constants, return-value, member-functions

I am trying to get a constant reference back by a method for the mapped value of an unordered_map. The unordered_map is a class member. However, the code below does not work and raises the error stated in the title.

I tried to change `const umap_int::mapped_type &` to `const int &` which did not work either. The standard example of returning a const reference to a variable of simple datatype (int, double, ...) worked.

```
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

typedef unordered_map<int, int> umap_int;

class class_A{

    public:

    class_A(){
        for(int k=0; k<3;++k)
            M[k] = k;
    }

    const umap_int::mapped_type & get_M(int key) const{
        return M[key];
    }

    private:

    umap_int M;

};

int main(){

    class_A A;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please dont call a member variable M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside const method you can only call for `M` its const member functions. Both `unordered_map::operator[]` overloads are *non-const* - [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at). So you cannot use it inside const `get_M`. You could remove *const* qualifier from `get_M` signature, or use `find` which has const overload but then you need to handle a case when mapped value doesn't exist for the passed key:

```
const umap_int::mapped_type & get_M(int key) const {
    //return M[key];
    auto it = M.find(key);
    if (it != M.end())
        return it->second;
    // do sth here ...
    // throw exception
    // make static variable with default value which will be accessed 
}
```

Comment: or with minimal change: `mutable umap_int M;` and don't change the function

Comment: Yes, it could be another solution, but then OP should add `mutex` to protect access to `M` collection. If we assume that *const* methods only read data, we can use them in many threads. Without mutex we would have data races while accessing map by `opearator[]` - it adds new item when key doesn't exist.